# how to print JTable with a specific printer (Microsoft Print to PDF) and a specific file's name without displaying the print dialog?

Tags: java, printing, jtable

The title is clear I think.
I have a java.lang.ClassCastException at the printerName's line and I don't know how to directly specify a path for the output pdf.

here's my code so far :

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());

    File file = null;
    MessageFormat header = null;
    MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page {0,number,integer}");

    if(choix.equals("Lc")){
        header = new MessageFormat("Liste des produits vendus le : " + date);
        file = new File("Z:/Enregistrements/FeuillesActiviteJour/ListeProduitsVendus_"+sdf.format(new Date())+".pdf");
    }
    else{
        header = new MessageFormat("Liste des Encaissements effectués le : " + date);
        file = new File("Z:/Enregistrements/FeuillesActiviteJour/ListeEncaissements_"+sdf.format(new Date())+".pdf");
    }

    Destination destination = new Destination(file.toURI());
    PrintService service = null;
    PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

for (PrintService service1 : services) {
    if (service1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Microsoft Print to PDF")) {
        service = service1;
    }
}
    PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
    set.add(destination);

try {
    table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer, false, set, false, service);
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TraitementFeuilleActivite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (HeadlessException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TraitementFeuilleActivite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrinterName` cannot be added to your `HashPrintRequestAttributeSet`. You should add it to a `HashPrintServiceAttributeSet`.

The `HashPrintRequestAttributeSet` is only able to contain objects of type [PrintRequestAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttribute.html) or subclasses of it.
That is why Java tries to cast the `PrintName` (which is of type [PrintServiceAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintServiceAttribute.html)) object to a `PrintRequestAttribute` which cannot be done as it does not inherit from that. -> *ClassCastException*